# GAE java dev server - ImagesService serving url issue on Windows platform

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We upload images to GCS and then generate serving url using ImagesService#getServingUrl to have resize and crop options. 
For dev server generated link looks something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_key:L2dzL3NpdGl6ZW5zLWJhY2tlbmQtZGV2LXAuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20vZDM5YzMyYmYtY2YzMS00YTIwLTk3NmQtYjY4YWU3ZGZhZmU1
```

and it is being served well on Mac/Linux dev PCs but for Windows we get this error ouput:

```
2017-09-21 17:15:31.755:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp2045766957-51: /_ah/img/encoded_gs_key:L2dzL3NpdGl6ZW5zLWJhY2tlbmQtZGV2LXAuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20vZDM5YzMyYmYtY2YzMS00YTIwLTk3NmQtYjY4YWU3ZGZhZmU1
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 79: C:\project\target\backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT\/_ah/img/encoded_gs_key:L2dzL3NpdGl6ZW5zLWJhY2tlbmQtZGV2LXAuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20vZDM5YzMyYmYtY2YzMS00YTIwLTk3NmQtYjY4YWU3ZGZhZmU1/index.html
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.<init>(PathResource.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.addPath(PathResource.java:304)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.getResource(StaticFileFilter.java:133)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.maybeServeWelcomeFile(StaticFileFilter.java:172)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Looks like a bug in GCS stub implementation. Does anybody know workaround, please?